# Plotting values of the same column grouped by an ID

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with R.

I have a tibble that have many columns, including these two...

```
Condition  Strength 
  A           0.05
  A           0.3
  A           0.2
  A           0.6
  A           0.2
  B           0.8
  B           0.4
  B           0.7
  B           0.9
```

I am trying to plot the data like this (then I will add a few more things)...

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = filter(condition == "A" %>% select(Strength)), 
                   y = filter(condition == "B" %>% select(Strength)))) +
  geom_point()
```

This gives me nothing.

So, what I want is to treat the strength as two different vectors dividing them considering the condition.

Comment: How do you know which condition `A` strength value goes with which condition `B` strength value? Randomly?

Comment: Well, I want to end up with a boxplot so I think that they do not need to go with each other

Comment: In your code, you used `geom_point`. That geometry plots points based on their `x` and `y` coordinates, and thus they have to go together.

Comment: So you recommend using a geom_boxplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want a boxplot?

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Condition, y = Strength, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_boxplot(show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

[See this tutorial](https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/boxplot.html) for more about `ggplot` and boxplots. (No affiliation)

Comment: That what I needed. Definitely need the tutorial.